# Serving static content from dynamic URLs

Tags: nginx

I've been searching all over the place trying to find a solution to serving static content from within varying sub-directories. Here is what I mean. All static content is located in:

> /usr/share/nginx/www/www.example.com/skin/

Images, JavaScript Libraries and Style Sheets respectfully:

> /usr/share/nginx/www/www.example.com/skin/css/
>
> /usr/share/nginx/www/www.example.com/skin/img/
>
> /usr/share/nginx/www/www.example.com/skin/js/

Each of these directories `css`, `img` and `js` have numerous other sub-directories.

**Problem:**
If you look at my server config you will see all requests are handled by index.phtml which includes the autoloader.php to dynamically load appropriate content based on the requested URI.

The problem I'm facing is static content with relative paths does not load for dynamic URLs:

i.e. Relative path to a JavaScript library: `skin/js/library/helloWorld.js`

This works:
https://www.example.com/skin/js/library/helloWorld.js

This doesn't work:

> https://www.example.com/foo/skin/js/library/helloWorld.js
>
> https://www.example.com/foo/bar/skin/js/library/helloWorld.js

Because the URLs are completely dynamic I need to be able to serve static content with any number of sub-directories before /skin/{...}

> https://www.example.com/{any number of dynamic sub-directories}/skin/js/library/helloWorld.js

**My Question:**
Is it possible to modify the $uri to omit `{any number of dynamic sub-directories}` and rewrite everything starting from /skin/{...} to https://www.example.com/skin/{...} ?

```
location ^(.*)/skin/(.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
    # Something like:
    # rewrite ^ https://www.example.com/skin/{requested static content} break;
    # or 
    # try_files /skin/{requested static content};
}
```

**My server config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$uri permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/www.example.com;
    index index.phtml;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
        rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$uri permanent;
    }

    location ^~ /autoloader.php {
            deny all;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.phtml;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 404 403 /error.phtml;
}
```

**Possible Solutions**

These are the solutions I would like to avoid:

- Use absolute paths for linking static content. (Bad for domain name
  changes)
- Add `location` for each sub-directory in /skin/ in my server
  config. (Not dynamic)
- Parse static content requests inside my
  index.phtml. (Seems messy...)

Sorry for the long post. I just wanted to clarify my situation. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not quite understanding why couldn't request url like "/skin/js/library/helloWorld.js" directly from you index.html, it will not be affected when the domain changes. It means request the file in the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

TIL: Coffee and a short break can do wonders haha.

Here is a solution for everyone who might come across this post searching for the same answer.

When linking static content using a relative path, i.e. an image in your HTML page:

```
<img src="skin/img/helloWorld.jpg" />
```

Located inside index.html and referenced from https://www.example.com the image will load correctly because the relative path will append to the end of the URL like so:

> https://www.example.com/skin/img/helloWorld.jpg

But if we move our index to a sub-directory, say:

> https://www.example.com/sub-directory/index.html

the image will not load because the request will look like this:

> https://www.example.com/sub-directory/skin/img/helloWorld.jpg

and since our `skin` directory is one level down the request will result in a 404.

**Solution**

To correctly reference static content from any sub-directory, just like in the previous example:

https://www.example.com/sub-directory/category/post/id/index.html

use `/skin/img/helloWorld.jpg` as the relative path:

```
<img src="/skin/img/helloWorld.jpg" />
```

the `/` at the very beginning of a relative path signifies to start from the ROOT of your web directory and then try to find the correct file from there. In this case, regardless where index.html is located, be it 10 directories deep the path to the image will always look like this:

> https://www.example.com/skin/img/helloWorld.jpg

So keep in mind relative paths: `skin/img/helloWorld.jpg` and `/skin/img/helloWorld.jpg` are **handled DIFFERENTLY**.

Comment: I just noticed your comment regarding my question and you had the solution all along. You are 100% right. Thank you Troy!

Comment: when a URL is referenced with a leading `/` that means this is relative to the root domain, so if you call `/images/img.jpg` inside `http://example.com/a/b/c/d/e...` it doesn't matter, it will always be relative to the domain: `http://example.com/images/img.jpg`, but without the leading `/` it will be relative to the current URI: `http://example.com/a/b/c/d/e/images/img.jpg`, **edit**: ok i just realized you already wrote that :D

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the static files request to the right directoty, for example :

```
location ^(.*)/skin/(.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
    rewrite "^.*/skin/(.*)$" /skin/$1 break;
}
```